# Azure pipeline schedules with fluid cron job

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines

I'm using the Azure pipeline to build and run my .NET console application on a Microsoft agent running synthetic monitoring. My project runs Selenium and pushes transactions to Log Analytics. This needs to run on a set interval time in an hour.

I would like to have more fluid timing of schedules in the Azure pipeline. Can I give variables or generate variables with random intervals instead of a fixed cron job?

**Current situation** - this gives an interval of fixed :15, :30, :45:

```
  - cron: '*/15 * * * *'
    displayName: Measurement scheme
    branches:
      include:
        - main
```

**Desired situation**

```
int n = Random(0,15)

  - cron: '$(n),$(n),$(n),$(n),$(n),$(n),$(n)...... * * * *'
    displayName: Measurement scheme
    branches:
      include:
        - main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry that you can’t give variables or generate variables with random intervals instead of a fixed cron job . Because  the following documentation has noted:"**You can’t use pipeline variables when specifying schedules**"

[Configure schedules to run pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Fprocess%2Fscheduled-triggers%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26tabs%3Dyaml&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7C84e9f6d288ec4619891a08dab8c2535d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638025442019606401%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=lsPelljOP2eg%2BsjqBB19TUGQY5ZirHmG%2B4n9rkXDr0w%3D&reserved=0)

[pipeline variable constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cHc8.png)

You may submit a suggestion at website below:

[feature request](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopercommunity.visualstudio.com%2FAzureDevOps%2Fsuggest%3Fspace%3D21&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7C84e9f6d288ec4619891a08dab8c2535d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638025442019606401%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=r2%2F3yio%2FSf2h0SrzC1YzJ1hZcUSValoAtZp%2FQ9dMClw%3D&reserved=0)

Comment: Thanks, I will then choose the most effective static cron job possible.